# Inside a GitLab CI job, how can I tell which version of GitLab Runner is being used?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

GitLab CI provides a [`CI_SERVER_VERSION` predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#predefined-variables-environment-variables) which is great for determining what version of GitLab was used to schedule the job, but how can a job get the version of GitLab Runner that is executing the job? I'm using the Shell executor on Windows 10.

This is for medical software where I need to check that the version of the runner matches what we validated.

Comment: Upstream issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41090

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with the predefined variables since they only contain `CI_RUNNER_DESCRIPTION`, `CI_RUNNER_ID` and `CI_RUNNER_TAGS`.

You could create a workaround by using the `environment` setting in the runner `config.toml` as described in [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) and the example:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "ruby-2.1-docker"
  url = "https://CI/"
  token = "TOKEN"
  limit = 0
  executor = "docker"
  builds_dir = ""
  shell = ""
  environment = ["ENV=value", "CI_RUNNER_VERSION=10.2"]
  clone_url = "http://gitlab.example.local
```

If you use stuff like Ansible, Puppet, Chef or another provisioning tool you could make sure they update the config when they upgrade the runner e.g.

Or create a bash script that replaces the CI_RUNNER_VERSION value in the config.toml based on a every day/night and restarts the runner service. That would be pretty easy.

You can get the version or your runner (and only the exact version) by running:

```
$ gitlab-runner --version | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```